# Utilisation de « souhait »

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai trouvé ce passage sur genius d'une célébrité qui s'appelle Jordy.

> Célèbre bébé-chanteur des années 1990, connu pour des horreurs d'une dance insipide à souhait telles que « Dur, dur, d'être un bébé » ou « Allison, c'est ma copine à moi.»

Je pense que je comprends le sens de la phrase, mais je ne suis pas familière avec cet usage particulier de « à souhait ».

Peut-on me montrer un autre exemple de cette forme d'usage ? ou une explication ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*À souhait* est une expression qui signifie "autant qu'on le souhaite", "selon ses désirs".

> Dans sa carrière, tout lui a réussi à souhait.
>
> Mon steak était tendre à souhait, c'était parfait.

Par exagération, l'expression peut prendre un sens de "beaucoup" ou "extrêmement".

De plus, dans le cas de votre exemple *insipide à souhait*, le ton de cet article me semble sarcastique, ce qui explique pourquoi l'auteur dit que sa musique est *insipide à souhait* (c'est une forme d'ironie: qui peut souhaiter qu'une danse soit insipide ?).

Comment: Dans ce contexte, je le vois plus comme une expression de "Au possible" ou plus familèrement "au taquet". Je pense qu'on est plus dans l'idée de beacuoup voire trop comme vous le dites en seconde partie. Dans la description de Jordi, ce serait une manière de dire que sa danse était des plus déplorables.

Comment: Un autre commentaire sur "dance": vu l'orthographe "dance" et non "danse", je pense plutôt qu'il s'agit du style musical (en gros, une musique électronique de danse des années 1990/2000, comme les chansons de Jordy), "dance" étant alors prononcé à l'anglaise.

Comment: Ou il pourrait s'agir tout simplement d'une fôte d'autaugraffe, surtout si ce text nous vient de l'internet...

Comment: 'Du , dur d'être un bébé" et "Alyson" sont des chansons qu'on peut classer dans le genre "dance music", et pas vraiment des "danses". Si on remplace le mot "dance" par "dance music", la phrase me semble faire plus de sens que si c'étaient des "danses".

Comment: Jordy etait reputé pour ses prestations scéniques. Mouvement de gauche a droite, regard dans le vide. Il se peut que le terme danse soit valide dans ce cas. Mais on s'égare du sujet.

Comment: C'est plutôt "autant qu'on peut le souhaiter" ie "autant que possible" car *de facto* on ne souhaite pas réellement que ce soit insipide à ce point...